Is there an issur of Tzad (trapping) when returning a pet hamster to its cage on Shabbos?
Putting the issue of muktzah aside, the question is- do poskim discuss whether or not a pet hamster is already considered trapped?
The baseline halacha is that a "domesticated" animal is already considered trapped and therefore may be put into a space that would otherwise be considered trapping the animal. The definition of "domesticated" (from what I have seen in sefarim from modern day poskim) includes:  1) a cooperative animal, 2) an animal which one knows will come back to its domain at a later time, even if it is currently running around and not trapped, 3) a submissive animal, 4) an animal that is obedient and doesn’t resist being confined.
An example of a domesticated animal is a pet cat which is comfortable with its owners. An example of an animal that comes back to its domain at a later time is a chicken which has been trained to return to its coop.
Hamsters sort of fit into some of the definition of "domesticated" to a certain extent, hence my question. I'm not asking for people's arguments one way or another, I think a compelling argument can be made for either position. I'd like to know if any posek has addressed and defined what a hamster is vis a vis this halacha.

I have taken it as a given because that is what I have seen lemaaseh in Shemiras Shabbos, Orchos Shabbos, Rabbi Ribiad and other sefarim.

Please put that in the question :)

Are you allowed to pick it up at all on shabbos? It's muktzah.

See Shulchan Aruch 316:12 with MB,depends if animal is domesticated or not ...
